# Regex for extracting SIP Number from SIP Header

Tags: php, regex, sip

Possible SIP from headers:

```
"unknown-caller-name" <sip:unknown-ani@pbx.domain.com:5066;user=phone>
"Henry Tirta" <sip:951@domain.com>
```

I need to extract SIP Number between `<sip:` & `@` from the above header in php using regex. This SIP number length will vary.

```
$from = "\"User Name\" <sip:199@pbx.testdomain.com>";
$matches = array();
$pattern = '/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.([A-Za-z0-9_-][A-Za-z0-9_]+)/';
preg_match($pattern,$from,$matches);
$number = explode('@', $matches[0])[0];
echo $number;
```

Any better way to do this ?

Comment: Questions asking for code **must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Great, removed my close vote. Now does that number always come after `sip:` and before `@` ?

Comment: No.May be string also will appear. like "unknown-caller-name" <sip:unknown-ani@pbx.domain.com:5066;user=phone>

Comment: So it's not a number but an ID ...

Comment: @HamZa - How did you *remove* your close vote? I wasn't aware that was possible.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I think it's new ! I discovered it by accident :) Click again on the close link and you should be able [to remove it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hdG3E.png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's make it simple:

```
$from = '"unknown-caller-name" <sip:unknown-ani@pbx.domain.com:5066;user=phone>';
if(preg_match('#<sip:(.*?)@#', $from, $id)){
    echo $id[1];
}else{
    echo 'no match';
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `<sip:` : match `<sip:`
- `(.*?)` : match and group everything ungreedy until ...
- `@` : `@` is found/matched.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a better way, but I did something shorter, and I used a named group in the regular expression

```
<?php
$pattern='/^(.*) <sip\:(?P<number>[0-9]+)@(.*)>$/';
$subject='"User Name" <sip:199@pbx.testdomain.com>';
preg_match($pattern,$subject,$matches);
echo $matches["number"];
?>
```

You can improve the expression by changing the (.*) parts, but I didn't know if you needed something specific for this

I hope this will help you, good luck with your code

Comment: May be string also will appear. like "unknown-caller-name" <sip:unknown-ani@pbx.domain.com:5066;user=phone>

Comment: you can modify the pattern to match it, with something like 
`$pattern='/^(.*) <sip\:(?P<number>[0-9]+|unknown\-caller\-name)@(.*)>$/';`

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '"User Name" <sip:199@pbx.testdomain.com>';

preg_match('/^(?:\"([^\"]+)\" )?\<sip\:(\d+)\@/i', $string, $matches);

// Output
array (size=3)
  0 => string '"User Name" <sip:199@' (length=21)
  1 => string 'User Name' (length=9)
  2 => string '199' (length=3)
```